Raster extract function on R return values incompletely
I am using R to extract the raster values based on the grid (polygon). The result extracts the values but with some missing data (NA) in the output. These missing values are located on the intersection of the boundary polygon and the grids. The following are the data I am using as well as the R script.

Vector data: 5 km resolution grid, boundary
Raster data: 5km resolution of NDVI raster, SPEI raster for 2002/4
Here is the link to the data

1.Data loading
smaller_area<- st_read("subset_area.shp")
grid <- st_read("GridData/grid_5km.shp")
grid_subset <- st_intersection(grid, smaller_area)
grid_subset$FID <- 1:nrow(grid_subset)

# Load the specific NDVI and SPEI files for April 2002
ndvi_file <- "NDVIdata/NDVI_mean2002_04.tif"
spei_file <- "SPEIdata/SPEI_1_month_2002_4.tif"

ndvi_raster <- raster(ndvi_file)
spei_raster <- raster(spei_file)


2. Clip the raster and extract the values
# Clip the raster files to the smaller area
clip_raster <- function(raster, extent) {
 cropped_raster <- crop(raster, extent)
 masked_raster <- mask(cropped_raster, extent)
 return(masked_raster)
}

ndvi_raster_subset <- clip_raster(ndvi_raster, smaller_area)
spei_raster_subset <- clip_raster(spei_raster, smaller_area)

# Extract values from rasters to the grid
ndvi_values <- exact_extract(ndvi_raster_subset, grid_subset, 'mean')
spei_values <- exact_extract(spei_raster_subset, grid_subset, 'mean')

# Create the final data frame
final_data <- grid_subset %>%
 st_drop_geometry() %>%
 mutate(
   FID = grid_subset$FID,
   year = 2002,
   month = 4,
   ndvi = ndvi_values,
   spei = spei_values
 )

# Save the result to a CSV file
write.csv(final_data, "final_data_2002_04.csv", row.names = FALSE)

The output csv. and the location of the missing values can be seen as the figure below, which are all on the boundary of the study area. I am certain there are actual ndvi, spei number on those grids but it couldn't be extracted. Is it because it only covered part of the grid? If so, how to extract the values if it only overlaps partially with the grids?


The problem is likely with the cropping and masking of the input rasters before running exact_extract. There is no need to do this - the values can be extracted from the original rasters directly.
Doing this, I get a result when extracting a single cell that is shown as missing data on your map:
> grid_subset %>% filter(FID == 39) %>% exact_extract(ndvi_raster, ., 'mean')
Warning in .local(x, y, ...) :
  Polygons transformed to raster CRS. To avoid on-the-fly coordinate transformation, ensure that st_crs() returns the same result for both raster and polygon inputs.
[1] 2022.849

For another cell I still get NaN:
> grid_subset %>% filter(FID == 21) %>% exact_extract(ndvi_raster, ., 'mean')
Warning in .local(x, y, ...) :
  Polygons transformed to raster CRS. To avoid on-the-fly coordinate transformation, ensure that st_crs() returns the same result for both raster and polygon inputs.
[1] NaN

But this seems expected when plotting the inputs in QGIS:


Thank you!  @dbaston. It is solved! Would you recommend to buffer a bit the boundary(polygon) so that the grids are all covered within the polygon? (e.g. buffer the length of the hypotenuse of the grid, at this case around 7100m since the grid width is 5000m)

Not totally sure I follow, but if you want to make sure that a grid like #21 in the image above picks up a value from your raster, you could use https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_fillnodata.html . Of course that could also affect the values of #24 in a way that might be undesirable.
